# How can I change input type="date" from "dd-mm-yyyy" to "dd-mm" without displaying year value in React application

Tags: html, reactjs, date, input

is there a possibility to display only month and day value from input type="date" selection?
Or maybe there is any other component that let me select and display only day of month? Thany you in advance for help!

Comment: Are you using any npm library?

Comment: You cannot withput JS, you could use a input field and parse the date yourself.

Comment: Probably this could help you, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372038/is-there-any-way-to-change-input-type-date-format

Comment: @sv12 I use html input element

Comment: Does this document answer your question? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date

Comment: @keikai Unfortunately no